# Python dictionary issue update values

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a problem with the python's dictionary.

```
import random

values = {"A" : [2,3,4], "B" : [2], "C" : [3,4]}


# this variable have to store as keys all the values in the lists kept by the variable values, and as values a list of numbers
# example of dictionary :
# {"2" : [2, 6 ,7 ,8, 8], "3" : [9, 7, 6, 5, 4], "4" : [9, 7, 5, 4, 3]}
dictionary = {}

for x in values.keys():
    listOfKeyX = values[x]
    newValues = []
    for index in range (0, 5):
        newValue = random.randint(0,15)
        newValues.append(newValue)
    for value in listOfKeyX:
        if value in dictionary.keys():
            for index in range (0, 5):
                #i want to update a value in dictionary only if the "if" condition is satisfied
                if(newValues[index] < dictionary[value][index]):
                    dictionary[value][index] = newValues[index]
        else:
            dictionary.setdefault(value, [])
            dictionary[value] = newValues
    print dictionary
```

I have a problem with the dictionary values when I'm trying to change them. I want to modify only pairs key-value that i selected through key = value but this piece of code changes all the dictionary values.
Can you suggest me a solution for this issue?

I try to explain what the algorithm does:
it iterates on the keys of the values variable and it keeps in the variable listOfKeyX the list linked to key. 
It creates some random values kept by newValues[].
After that it iterates on the listOfKeyX
if the value taken from the list not exists already in the dictionary.keys() it stores all the newValues list in dictionaty[value],
if the value taken from the list already exists in the dictionary.keys() it takes the list kept by dictionary[value] and tries to upgrade it in some way.

Comment: What is this code doing, exactly? What does `listValues` have `.keys`? What is `hashFamily`? `maxFunction`?

Comment: hashFamily it's just a function that returns the hash value of x based on hashedIndex, maxFunction is the maximum number of iteration thus it's a costant value. listValues it's a function that returns a set of words or number and it returns a dictionary object.

Comment: So if it returns a dictionary, why is `list` in its name? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You're right I'm sorry; I'll be more accurate next time. However my problem is not on the whole code but only when i try to  change the value of minWiseMap with a given key. minWiseMap it's a dictionary that stores {key : [list of hased value]} and when i try to update this list with the given key the code changes either the other list values

Comment: Then please read the linked article and provide a minimal example that other users can **actually run** to recreate the issue.

Comment: I edited my previous post and i hope that new post is good enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first loop, you run this code three times:

```
dictionary.setdefault(value, [])  # create brand new list
dictionary[value] = newValues  # ignore that and use newValues
```

This means that every value in `dictionary` is a reference to the same list. I'm still not totally sure what the outcome you're looking for is, but replacing the lines above with:

```
dictionary[value] = newValues[:]  # shallow copy creates new list
```

will at least mean they don't share a reference.

Comment: Yeah! I'm a beginner with python and i don't know so much about it. However thanks!